# How to map strings to Observable<boolean> values in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

(I am new to angular but now I have to work on a project)

I've got an `Observable<boolean>` in my angular component. In the template I want to set the HTML-attribute *dir* to "rtl" if `rtl$ == true;` otherwise to "ltr".

Template

```
<div [dir]="rtl$ | async">
```

Component

```
rtl$: Observable<boolean>;
```

How can I map the boolean-values to those strings reactive?

Thanks for help in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ternary operator should work in your case:

```
[dir]="(rtl$ | async) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'"
```

Or if you don't want to have this logic in template then move it to component:

**ts**

```
dir$ = this.rtl$.pipe(map(rtl => rtl ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'));
```

**html**

```
[dir]="dir$ | async"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think below code can work for you:

**TS**

```js
get rtlString$() {
   return this.rtl$.pipe(
       map(rtl => rtl ? 'rtl' : 'ltr')
   );
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div [dir]="rtlString$ | async">
```

Answer (score 0):

the better way is to use `ngClass` as follows:

.CSS

```
.rtlClass { direction: rtl };
.ltrClass { direction: ltr };
```

HTML

```
<div [ngClass]="(rtl$ | async ) ? 'rtlClass' : 'ltrClass' ">
```